# Read an excel file with Python and modify it without changing the style

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a excel file which has specific format, font and color etc. I would like to read it using Python libraries like pandas (pd.read_excel) and just modify a few cells without affecting the style. Is it possible? Currently, when I read and write using pandas, the style changes and it seems difficult to make the complex style in Python again.

Is there a way to **load and store the format/style of Excel file when we are reading it**, to be applied when it is being saved? I just want to modify the value of few cells.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288801/how-to-preserve-excel-text-formatting-when-reading-writing-excel-files-with-pand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the openpyxl library like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook("test.xlsx") # Your Excel file
worksheet = workbook.active # gets first sheet

for row in range(1, 10):
    # Writes a new value PRESERVING cell styles.
    worksheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=f'NEW VALUE {row}')

workbook.save("test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set_properties() function.
Further use can be viewed at [How to change the font-size of text in dataframe using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284208/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-text-in-dataframe-using-pandas)

Comment: Thanks but it is not just font, I would like to avoid headache of setting a complex style in Python. For example, read the format from excel and store with same format.