# Copy excel sheet with style in another already-created file with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a Python code that, at the end of the process, it creates an Excel file with several worksheets, what I'm trying to do is copy a sheer from another file that is read with its exact format (cells with background color, different fonts and letter sizes, etc) and paste it as it is in the main file without affecting the other previously-created sheets, the method that I'm currently using doesn't allow me to do that because it overwrites the new file over the previously-created one. Does someone have a suggestion or way of doing this?

The method I'm currently using, which is obtained from: [Read an excel file with Python and modify it without changing the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324914/read-an-excel-file-with-python-and-modify-it-without-changing-the-style):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

workbook2 = load_workbook("readme tab.xlsx") # Your Excel file
worksheet2 = workbook2.active # gets first sheet

for row in range(1, 10):
    # Writes a new value PRESERVING cell styles.
    worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=1, value=f'NEW VALUE {row}')

workbook2.save(path)
```

Reference of the code I'm using, in order:

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

path = r"Archivo.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Data']
ws = workbook.add_worksheet('Graph')

worksheet.set_column(1, 29, 30)

writer.save()

from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

workbook2 = load_workbook("readme tab.xlsx") # Your Excel file
worksheet2 = workbook2.active # gets first sheet

for row in range(1, 10):
    # Writes a new value PRESERVING cell styles.
    worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=1, value=f'NEW VALUE {row}')

workbook2.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a sheet (including its format style) with the method `add_sheet`.
And assuming that `workbook` is the workbook to which you're adding the sheet :

##### Replace :

```
workbook2 = load_workbook("readme tab.xlsx") # Your Excel file
worksheet2 = workbook2.active # gets first sheet

for row in range(1, 10):
    # Writes a new value PRESERVING cell styles.
    worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=1, value=f'NEW VALUE {row}')

workbook2.save(path)
```

###### By :

```
ws2 = load_workbook('readme tab.xlsx').active
ws2._parent = workbook
workbook._add_sheet(ws2)
workbook.save(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm having a hard time applying your code. I should note that the variable ```workbook``` is the one which I'm trying to add the new sheet to saved in the variable ```path```. Also, what is the variable ```s``` that you are using? Is it ```ws```? Here's what I'm trying ``` from openpyxl import load_workbook```
```ws2 = load_workbook('readme tab.xlsx')['Readme']```
```ws2._parent = workbook```
```workbook._add_sheet(ws2)```
```writer.save()```

Comment: Now, it's much more clear for me. I edited my answer. Check it out !

Comment: Thank you! I tried the new answer but I'm still getting the error ```object of type 'Worksheet' has no len()``` in the line ```workbook._add_sheet(ws2)```

Comment: And if you add `workbook = load_workbook(path)` right before `ws2 = load_workbook('readme tab.xlsx').active` ?

Comment: That sort of did the trick. However, when opening the Excel file which it is saved to, the sheet deleted the original format and instead added a yellow background to every single cell.

Comment: I should also note that, when opening the Excel file, it displayed an error that mentioned that it had to "remove unreadable features and will recover as much as it can".